# Automatically Android application upload

Tags: android, google-play

I've just one simple question:

Is it possible to upload an Android Application (.Apk) directly to Google Play? Either through command-line or an Google API?

This is because we are building Android Application through a 'builder' and we want to Upload them right away to Google Play instead of going to Google Play itself and upload the .apk there.

**Edit:** Like the answer below, there is now an API for doing this : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an api now:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

It only allows for uploads of existing apps. Not creation of new ones.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Google supplied or approved API for automating uploads to Google Play.

You could in theory write a script that logs in for you, and sends the content to Google, but AFAIK nobody has done this yet, so you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: +1 With out user credentials we cant login to google server to upload an apk.till now there is not public API to upload externally other then Google play.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [`gradle-play-publisher`](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) gradle plugin to automatically upload to the Google Play store.